# CentOS 7 Missing /etc directory

Tags: centos, centos-7

Freshly installed CentOS 7 Server with GUI, cannot locate /etc in the file manager. As well as I cannot cd into it either.

Comment: Can you `mkdir` it?

Comment: I mean, it should be there. What do you get from an `ls /` ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

1. First check in which directory you are in via issuing **pwd** command
2. Go back via issuing **cd ..** command untill you reach /root directory (you can check anytime in what current directory you're in via **pwd** or **~**)
3. Issue **ls** command and you find etc directory among other directories.